# Which structure is better for searching inventory in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Which structure is better for queries like:

Person has 5 bananas and 1 apple.

Person has 5 bananas or 1 apple.

Nested?

```
{
    id: 1,
    has: 
    [
        {
            'name': 'banana',
            'quantity': 5,
        },
        {
            'name': 'apple',
            'quantity': 1,
            'species': 'gala'
        }
    ]
}
```

Or fixed slots?

```
{
    id: 1,
    slot1: {
            'name': 'banana',
            'quantity': 5,
            },
    slot2: {
            'name': 'apple',
            'quantity': 1,
            'species': 'gala'
            }
    slot3: null,
    slot4: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested approach is simpler: You can do a simple nested query [1], instead of having to do slot1 OR slot2 OR... Indexing each "slot" as a document would be even simpler, if Person had no other fields.

[1] http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query.html

Comment: Indexing each "slot" as a document, would result in slots appearing in result lists instead of persons. It means that the same person could appear multiple times in the same result list. So, it would be necessary to either use faceted search or remove duplicates on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
{
  id: 1,
  banana: {
        'quantity': 5,
  },
  apple: {
        'quantity': 1,
        'species': 'gala'
  }
}
```

then the queries are simple. via [query string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) your queries will look like:

```
banana.quantity:5 AND apple.quantity:1
```

and

```
banana.quantity:5 OR apple.quantity:1
```

Comment: I estimate there could be 1000 different items. There will be more than just bananas and apples. Is this really a good idea?

Comment: it is not clear to me from your question: is every slot a separate docuement?